# 'No service was found." error in Spring and jQuery (ajax call)

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, tomcat, http-post

I have a Java server with multiple GET and POST requests under the Spring Framework which work just fine. Now, I have created a jsp file within my project to create a simple form (CustomerID, Title, Message). On clicking the submit button of the form, I want to POST the form-data in JSON format to my service. This service call (POST request) works just fine when I trigger it using Advanced REST Client. However, this particular front-end of the form doesn't open in the browser when deployed on the Tomcat server. Instead, I get "No Service was found." displayed on my screen.

After fiddling around with my web.xml, I realized that if I delete the following code:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ecvServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.***.platform.ecvcheck.NodeStatusServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ecvServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/node</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

from my web.xml, then the form.jsp file opens just fine. But none of the GET and POST requests (even the ones which were unrelated to form.jsp) wouldn't work. And because of this, no service would get called upon hitting the Submit button.

My final web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>feedex-app</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/appContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.***.platform.config.PlatformContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<display-name>feedex-app</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Can someone please help me with how to incorporate the front-end bit in a Tomcat server (webapp)?

Thank you!

Comment: where you placed the front-end files?

Comment: In the webapp folder (outside WEB-INF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following fixed the problem:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>static-resources-list</param-name>
  <param-value>/(\w)+.html</param-value>
</init-param>
```

My final web.xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">


<display-name>feedex-app</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/appContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.***.platform.config.PlatformContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>static-resources-list</param-name>
        <param-value>/(\w)+.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ecvServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.***.platform.ecvcheck.NodeStatusServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ecvServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/node</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>feedex-app</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CXFServlet url mapping is the problem. You gave the mapping as /*. So all the requests, even the static resources are routed to CXFServlet. Try making the CXFServlet mapping to something else. It will work just fine. You don't need static-resources-list.